# Connecting to local database on Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssh

Using DBforge to try and connect to a local MSSQL database on an Azure Ubuntu 18 VM, I am getting this error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open
a connection to SQL Server)
```

I have:

1. Enabled SSH on the inbound rules.
2. I can SSH into the Azure VM using PuTTY
3. I have tried both the host name (`xx.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com`) and the public IP address (`13.82.xx.xx`) to try and connect, both give this error.
4. I can connect to the website running on the VM by using the host name, and going to the public IP address shows the Apache landing page.
5. The website is running 100%, and I can log in, so the database instance is running.
6. I followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297475/how-to-find-sql-server-running-port), and I confirm my server is listening on port 1433. (Log entry: `Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 1433].`)
7. Port 1433 is not blocked by a firewall. I have disabled the Azure firewall for testing purposes.
8. Various other answers suggest I must go into services.msc etc., but this is a Linux VM, so those won't work either.

I am getting the same error using SSMS, and none of the answers here seem to work for my specific case. All of them speak about connecting to an Azure SQL database, which this is not.

Any idea what else I can try?

Comment: I can add to this that port 1433 being blocked in the firewall is not the case, as I have switched off the firewall on Azure for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I have neglected to set up a subnet in Azure portal. I am connected now.

Answer (score 0):

If you could see this message (`Server is listening on [ 'any' 1433]`) in SQL Error log it means SQL Server level configuration has been set, i.e. enable TCP/IP protocol, restart service..

So now you must focus at network level, make sure the port number `1433` not getting blocked at network devices such as VLAN and firewall rules, while you can do SSH and connect to website that hosted by same VM it means the specific ports (SSH: 22, Website: 80 or custom port) are not getting blocked, similarly you have to open the port `1433` in-order to connect the SQL Server instance.